# How can I survive when using squishy (weak) champions?

Tags: league-of-legends

I sometimes play with somewhat squishy (weaker) champions, and usually I can survive however I die more than I'd like to admit. How can I survive longer/better?

Usually I try to go in (behind minions) and get a few shots in then move back again. Sometimes if an enemy champion targets me I'll fight back while trying to evade.

Comment: Wards, wards and more wards. Oh did i mention placing wards?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I'm sure they'll help out, but I doubt they'll sprout legs and save me :p.

Comment: correct, but warding and map awareness makes you know where you can go safely to escape.

Comment: Have you ever tried shouting: 'NOOB TANK SAVE ME!!!!!!!!!!' . I've seen loads of people use that, who knows it might work ;)

Comment: @Lyrion LOL. I'm sure all the pros do that! :p

Comment: Movement speed runes wouldn't hurt either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When asking how to better survive, the first question is, what exactly is out there trying to kill you?

**Problem 1: Harass**

A lot of champions have really annoying harassment that slowly but steadily reduces you to below half health, at which point they come in for a kill. Sometimes this comes in the form of skill shots (Lux's Lucent Singularity, Ezreal's Mystic Shot), other times it can be auto attacks (like most AD carries), or even some point and click abilities (Akali's Mark of the Assassin, Jax's Leap Strike). The common factor is one way or another, they keep wearing you down to the point where they can easily kill you.

**Solution 1: Sustain**

There's three different things you can do against harass-heavy lanes. The first is to buy some sort of armor/magic resistance so their harass does less damage. Against heavy physical damage you might take cloth armor and 5 potions as your starting items, for instance.

The second thing is buying some sustain. This means life steal (for AD champions), spell vamp (for AP champions), or health potions (for everyone). These items give you back some health over time, and if you're farming well can make staying in lane much easier. If you find yourself buying a lot of health potions, consider grabbing a Crystalline flask, as it'll be useful all through the early-mid game, and is definitely more gold efficient if you remember to use it.

The third and final thing is to simply recall sooner. Yeah, it sucks being forced out of lane, but it's better than giving your lane opponent another kill. Sometimes you're best off admitting defeat and recalling, so you can come back with a full health bar, a couple new items, and a chance to turn the tables on your opponent.

**Problem 2: Burst**

So you're just walking along in bottom lane at high health, last hitting creeps, when all of a sudden the enemy Blitzcrank turns and rocket grabs you. Meanwhile their AD carry continues shooting you with auto attacks and a couple of abilities, and before you can run away you've died yet again.

Or perhaps you're up in top lane against Riven, and she activates her ultimate, dashes to you, stuns you, uses her broken wings/auto attack combo, before finishing you off with an ignite and wind slash. From full health to death in just a few seconds, and you have no idea how to stop it.

**Solution 2: Defense**

If the enemy laner has enough power to take down 80% of your life (or worse, all of it) in a single combo, sometimes all you can do is put your normal build on hold for a mid level defensive item so you can survive. If you're up against AD damage, you'll likely want a Chain Vest, or possibly a Warden's Mail. If you're going against magic damage, a Negatron cloak is a good buy. (AP mids might also build Chalice of Harmony into Athene's Unholy Grail.) A Giant's belt is a good catch-all buy for the extra 380 health, and can be later finished into a Warmog's armor (or some other useful item) for even more survivability.

If crowd control is a problem, you can choose Mercury's treads as your T2 boots (they're generally amazing anyway), and they even reduce magic damage as a bonus. Conversely, Ninja Tabi is great against physical damage, particularly auto attacks.

Finally, if the enemy's combo depends on them landing a skill shot (Blitzcrank's Rocket Grab, Lux's Light Binding), then get your tier two boots as soon as possible, and stay behind your minions (if they block said skill shot). The fact of the matter is, there's a lot of instances in League of Legends where getting hit by a skill shot will lead to your death, so the only thing you can do is practice dodging them. Whatever you do, don't stay still, and don't run in a straight line.

**Problem 3: The Jungler**

Last (and possibly most annoying), we have the Jungler. This is the guy that jumps out of the bushes on the side of your lane to murder you, stopping your onslaught against your lane opponent, and ruining an otherwise decent laning phase. (Of course, other enemy champions aside from the jungler can do this, he's just the most likely to ruin your day.)

**Solution 3: Sight Wards**

The fact of the matter is, most champions in league of legends are not equipped to fight two opponents at once, and trying to do so is a recipe for disaster. The best thing to do is avoid fighting the jungler, and the best way to do that is by seeing them coming. A mere 75 gold investment (or 150 gold if you're the mid laner) is enough to ward the bush(es) by the river, and keep their jungler from surprising you. If you see him in the bushes, fall back and wait by your tower. Those few minion kills are not worth your life.

If you don't have any wards left, and you know their jungler is out there, play back in the lane. A good rule of thumb is that being on your side of the river is fairly safe, being about even with the river is risky, and being on the enemy's side of the river is very dangerous.

Finally, keep in mind that a couple of champions have ways to bypass your wards entirely. Someone like Twisted Fate or Pantheon can just teleport on top of you, and turn what seemed like an advantage into your death. Be very careful about engaging an enemy champion if one of those guys has their ultimate available.

**Other things you can do**

Remember, League of Legends is a team game, and you have allies is well. Sometimes the enemy champion counters yours, or they got an early advantage, or they're just outright better than you. If that's the case, ask for help! A couple of ganks from your jungler (or even other laners) can force them to play back a little further and respect your space a little. In emergency situations, you can have someone else take over your lane, and try your luck somewhere else. Remember, it doesn't help your team if the enemy laner 5-0's you in the first 12 minutes, and if they can do anything to help out, they definitely should.

Also, keep in mind that the laning phase is not the end of the game. Some champions focus on the early game, dominating their opponent and setting the tone for the rest of the match. However, other champions only become truly powerful in the late game, and tend to have difficult or risky early laning phases. (See: Veigar). Don't give up just because the enemy team is fed, as good teamfighting can turn around a lot of bad situations, and that 5-0-3 Pantheon might just end the game 6-8-7.

Last but not least, sometimes the enemy team is simply better than you, and runs over you and your allies at every turn. Don't get discouraged, it happens. There's an incredible number of champions in League of Legends, most of which are quite devestating under the right circumstances, especially if you don't know how to handle them. If you're having a lot of trouble with a certain champion, check a guide on them (to figure out their abilities), try a few different champions against them, and ask around for help. It might still be a struggle, but there's a way to deal with everything in this game, if only you can find it.

Answer (score 2):

if you play a squishy champion your probably are AD carry or mage.

**Early game:**

Just keep last hitting the minions especially if your ranged you can stay close to your tower without losing any CS.

Most Squishy champion have an escape of some sort (teleport, dash or speed boost) make sure to save it till you get ganked by their jungler or when your lane enemy goes for the offence (unless you think you can win a 1 v 1). Make sure you don't feed its better that you wait and only farm under tower till your jungler comes then giving away free kills

**Mid and late game:**

The pro of a squishy is that you can deal tons of damage. This also make you priority of the enemy. your worst enemy is CC (stuns, slows, fears). Make sure you know what enemy champion have CC and if they used it already. If you get caught in a stun and 5 enemy dive you are death before you know it. so be sure to go in after the tank, it might sound mean but its better that they spend 5 second killing him(while you damage the enemy) then them killing you in a quarter of a second.

Always make sure that you know where the enemy team is, if you cant just stay in a safe place (not near unwarded bushes).

**Other notes:**

Also try to recognize when you cant escape, when you get caught by ash's slow arrows just and you don't got any escapes. turn around and fight maybe you both die, or make the enemy low health so he has to recall (this way your team has a better change to survive till you come back alive.)

If you still get killed a lot, it's sometimes smart to build a guardians angels for defence, but make sure you don't sacrifice your damage for survivability.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so lets cover whats already been discussed in the answers we have.

1. Use your range to your advantage as **most** squishies are ranged and just out CS your opponent.
2. Use your escapes wisely.
3. Don't feed.
4. Know your opponent, and use your knowledge to not get caught.
5. Stay behind your tank.
6. Ward effectively, for escape and map control.
7. If you get caught turn and fight in hopes you will do enough damage to stop them from steamrolling you team.
8. If you are still dieing a lot, build defensively.

All great advice, all things to keep in mind while playing. But in reality none of this advice will help your gameplay. Its all up to how you play, trading, warding, and most importantly patience.

Players get so caught up in that if they sacrifice everything but their life to get a kill they did good. **WRONG**

If you sacrifice ignite, flash, ult and come within a hit of dieing and all you got is a kill *slow clap*. You just accomplished very little and your probably about to get ganked by their jungler for a 1 for 1 swap or you have to recall yourself. Now if you knocked your opponent down to a hit away from health and they got away and you have the **PATIENCE** to not tower dive and risk it all and they have to recall. Well now you get to sit their unopposed gathering gold and XP from CS. In the time it takes your opponent to get back health and run back you have gained more from last hitting then you could from 2 kills. Do it again, send them home again (if they get away) taking little to no damage. Third time back you will wreck them, and you can feed feed feed.

Nothing anyone says to you or no matter how well you play, if you start lacking patience and take high risks just to get a kill, you will probably end up feeding. Granted it works most of the time, heck even I get caught up in the moment and will tower dive recklessly.

It seems I have got caught up and have primarily focused on solo lanes (its what I do most). But I really don't need to add much more for duo bot. Personally I find that 2 for 1 swaps arent all that great either. The only exception is if the support is having a derp moment and doesn't give up the kill to his ADC. (although I have seen a soraka go from support to carry, eventually carring her team to victory) The risk just isnt worth it, freeze your lane cs, cs and cs some more. Let them push so your jungler can gank, let that 3v2 come into play and get a free double kill.

All in all what i'm trying to get across is, **Wouldn't you rather get something for free then pay for it?**

Answer (score 0):

Place wards in strategic places to warn you soon enough about incoming gank/invade.

Try using champion with disengage mechanism

I take you play ADC? How about Ezreal? Skills rank order Q>E>W>R

Save your E for disengages live long and happily ever after...

Answer (score 0):

Play with more care, like Adrian said, wards help in this process. Be aware of the players against you in your lane, what there damage output is on there abilities so you can heal on time. Sometimes you are up against a hero that is just a lot better in the early game, then just play with care and feed yourself later. So it really depends on the hero you are up against, try playing all of them so you know the ins and outs of each one.